# Dynamically generated SSRS reports

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix, reporting-services-2012

Is it possible to dynamically create SSRS tablix? I have a pretty complex requirement.

I have created tables in which I fill "metadata" for reports, i.e.:

- column names
- row names
- row/column levels (parent/child)
- font colours
- font sizes
- valid from/valid to attributes
- translations

Then, I generate queries from this metadata, and join them on fact tables. So each query returns data as it should.

I generate data in levels, so you always know, in which level you're currently. So, you get data in the following form (I can change it, if that would ease creating of reports):

```
Row Text | Level 1 Text | Level 2 Text | Level 3 Text | Level 4 Text | Level 5 Text | Value
```

Basically, SSRS doesn't have to sum anything, it just shows the data. But here's where I get into trouble. I don't know, how to achieve a normal-looking report. 
I have made 5 column groups (5 is the highest number of levels in any report), and every one is a child to previous one. Row groups get hidden based on the max level of current query, so if the query only has data on level 1, only 1 row is shown.

But here comes the tricky part. I have a report, that has data like this:

[image]

If some data is on level 5, and some on level 1 (others everywhere in between), the data on level 1 has 4 empty rows...

So, my report shows a lot of empty cells. Either that, or I show the same text for all 5 levels. Is there a smart way to address this issue? I can even change the whole concept, as I'm still early in development.

EDIT:

Here is one of the exact reports that has to be generated dynamically (it's a public template):
[ssrs template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXgXt.png)

Comment: It might be easier to visualise if you showed your data and what you currently think you want to achieve. It tricky to guide you when the sample you showed isn't represented clearly in you layout mock-up. Maybe mock something up in Excel and post a screen grab and sopmebody may be ale to help you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've added a screenshot of the exact template.

Comment: could you add a sample of data as it's stored in your database. And also state if there are any calculations done within the report or database. e.g. Is Total Risk Exposure Amount, the sum of the subsequent 4 columns. Ideally show a few rows of data rather than a single one as it might be that the report can be laid out vertically rather than horizontally but showing a few rows will help clear that up.

Comment: The report has to be as it's shown in the picture. Nothing can be done here. No calculations are done in SSRS (not even totals, everything is produced in SQL). Maybe it would be a better question if I've asked how the dataset for such report should look?

Comment: that's fine but I'd still like to see a sample with data in it. As it stands, it looks  like just a very wide table which would have to be replicated exactly in your dataset.